# libgdx confusion about position units

Tags: android, opengl-es, libgdx, perspectivecamera

I started work on libgdx a day before. I wanted to create a triangle whose points should be such that two corners should be at bottom left and bottom right and one point at top middle of  screen. I am using perspective camera. My code example is:

```
public class Test1 implements ApplicationListener{

    PerspectiveCamera camera;
    Mesh triangle;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, 45, 45 / (Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight()));
        camera.near = 1;
        camera.far = 200;
        triangle = createTriangle();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        GL10 gl = Gdx.gl10;
        gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        camera.update();
        camera.apply(gl);

        triangle.render(Gdx.gl10.GL_TRIANGLES);

    }

    public Mesh createTriangle() {
        float[] vertices = {-45f, -27f, -67,
                45f, -27f, -67,
                0, 27f, -67
        };

        short[] indices = {0,1,2};
        Mesh mesh = new Mesh(true, 3, 3, new VertexAttribute(Usage.Position, 3, ShaderProgram.POSITION_ATTRIBUTE));
        mesh.setVertices(vertices);
        mesh.setIndices(indices);
        return mesh;


    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

I was reading that OpenGL is unitless so I decided to have 45 units wide and accordingly set its height. When I executed the application, the triangle is not as I expected. It is smaller than the width and height of the screen. I have no prior experience in 3D. Kindly guide me where I am wrong?
Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You say you wanted to create a rectangle? You have only specified 3 vertices? Did you mean Triangle and if so, what seems to be the problem with your result?

Cheers

**EDIT 1:**
Having reread your question I apologise for the answer I gave.

You need to implement the resize function, creating your camera there as it is called once when the window is created before render is called. Something along the lines of

```
@Override
public void resize(int width, int height) {
   float aspectRatio = (float) width / (float) height;
   camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67,2f * aspectRatio, 2f);
}
```

should be what you're looking for. Read more about it [here](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectionViewportCamera) in the camera section. It may be about an orthographic camera, but the basic principle still applies

**Edit 2:**
Units in OpenGl are application specific. You have to set up the units you use.

There are however conventions, for instance by defualt the camera will be "looking" down the negative Z axis, with the positive X to the right and positive Y up. This is called a right hand system.

You have set up your 3D camera to have a view width of 45 (so an object at the camera with a width of 45 would fill the screen) and a height of 45 over the aspect ratio. Something we must remember is that objects in 3D that are far away are smaller than when they are up close. So you may have been expecting the triangle to fill the screen, however the Z coordinate of the points of the triangle are far away (67 from the camera) so it makes the triangle look smaller.

If you are only interested in 2D then use something called an `OrthographicCamera` which makes it so what you draw does not change size with distance from the camera (it has no *perspective*)

Comment: The thing you mentioned is not the issue I have. I want to understand the screen units used by GL, how to define them and use appropriately?

Comment: I Have Edited my original Post again